# JavaScript function sequence (Phaser game)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

can anyone explain how the code below works ? this is a timed animation  that uses the Phaser Javascript framework.

I can't work out how this works in sequence, e.g. how each function is triggered, doIntro0() followed by doIntro1()

For brevity , I have ommited the majorty of doIntro functions.

```
showIntro(); // initial call 

    var introFlags = new Object();
    function showIntro(){
      if (!introFlags.step0){
        if (!introFlags.doingStep0){
          introFlags.doingStep0 = true;
          doIntro0();
        }
        return
      }

      if (!introFlags.step1){
        if (!introFlags.doingStep1){
          introFlags.doingStep1 = true;
          doIntro1();
        }
        return
      }
    }

     function doIntro0(){
      player.animations.play("rest");
      player.x = 160+32;
      princess.animations.play("rest0");
      princess.x = 240;
      graves.alpha = 0;
      devil.alpha = 0;
      armour = game.add.sprite(140,354,"armour");
      setTimeout(endIntro0,500);
    }

    function endIntro0(){
      introFlags.step0 = true;
    }

    function doIntro1(){
      blackBg.alpha = 0.2;
      setTimeout(endIntro1,2000);  
    }

    function endIntro1(){
      introFlags.step1 = true;
    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

Comment: Ok , I have worked this out !